# How to post form data via ajax to a python script?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

I'm struggling with a python program and an ajax request. I'm trying to get some data from my Javascript into the python program, the normal method I've been using .getfirst(field name) doesn't work which I assume is because the request is via ajax (sorry, I'm quite new to all this) so I've tried using the following code

Python:

```
import MySQLdb
import cgi, cgitb

def index(req):

    # Create instance of FieldStorage
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()

    # Get data from fields
    dtbox = form.getvalue('dt')
    tmbox = form.getvalue('tm')

    con = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mydb')

    with con:
        cur = con.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        s = "SELECT tmp, watts FROM currentcost WHERE dt ='" + dtbox + "' and tm like '" + tmbox + "%'"
        cur.execute (s)
        rows = cur.fetchall()

        x=""
        y=""
        for row in rows:
            x=x+row["watts"]+","
            y=y+row["tmp"]+","

    x="data:["+x+"]"
    y="data:["+y+"]"

    con.close()

    req.write(x)
```

Javascript snippet:

```
function draw(handleResponse) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/currentcost.py",
        data: {dt: frm.dt, tm: frm.tm},
        success: function(response){
            handleResponse(response);
        }
    });

<form name="frm" target="ifrm">
    <iframe name="ifrm" id="ifrm" style="display:none"></iframe>
        <fieldset style="width:300px">
            <legend>Chart Date and Time</legend>
            Alter the date and time settings <br>
            Date:
            <select name="dt">
```

I'm expecting the form values dt and tm to be transferred to the python program where it will pick them out and run through my select query ... all I get back is a blank :-(

Thanks in anticipation of your help

Chris

Comment: I've fixed the formatting in your question. And please learn the difference between Java and Javascript.

Comment: You don't seem to define `frm` in your JS. Is it defined somewhere else? You should show where.

Comment: This isn't related to your Javascript question, but your current code is vulnerable to *SQL injections*.

Comment: @Daniel Sorry, must have been rushing too much, I do understand difference between Java and Javascript. I've editted my code above and added the few lines which refer to the form definitions (I've not included the whole page as its huge). I think I've been doing this for so long now I can't see the wood for the trees!! Any help would be appreciated

Comment: @Andre Thanks, I've not even looked at SQL Injection issues yet and as its running on my Raspberry PI its not a huge priority, but I take your point, once working I need to look at these points. Thanks

Comment: I've removed the POST line and changed the data line to data: "12345", I can see the command line being passed is currentcost.py?12345 and the error is now TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType'Is there a way to parse this command line in the script and construct the data line myself?

Answer (score 1):

Your ajax call should be of type `"POST"`, and you can serialize the fields from the form using `.serialize()`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/currentcost.py",
    type: "POST",
    data: $("form[name='frm']").serialize(),
    success: function(response){
        handleResponse(response);
    }
});
```

**Edit**

You should not typically use GET requests for form submission. That said, the ajax GET should look like:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "/currentcost.py",
    data: {dt: $("#dt").val(), tm: $("#tm").val() },
    success: function(response){
        handleResponse(response);
    }
 });
```

This assumes you have inserted the attribute `id="dt"` into the first element and `id="tm"` into the second element.

Comment: Thanks, its been one of those days. One step forward two steps back! I added your suggestion but now the .py is returning "Method not implemented" ... any ideas?

Comment: Are you using apache and mod_python? The reason I ask is because doing `def index` and `req.write` seems to be apache terminology rather than python and CGI.

Comment: Yes, I'm using apache2 and mod_python. To be honest I'm learning this via the internet and scrabbling for bits of code, combining with my more traditional knowledge of Windows and VB!

Comment: If I remove the POST line and alter the data line to "12345" the error I now get is TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' but I can see the command line passed is currentcost.py?12345. Is there a way to parse the data within the python script and constrruct the data line myself?

Comment: Apparently there is a known issue with ajax POST in older versions of mod_python that was fixed in mod_python 3.2.10 or later. What version are you using?

Comment: I'm running libapache2-mod_python 3.3.1.9

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a mod_python expert. It sounds like something is wrong there, though. Edited the answer for ajax get requests.

Comment: Thanks, I can feel I'm almost there. The last thing eluding me is how do I get the values passed in the currentcost.py? I was looking at functions like urlparse.parse_qs() but you need the URL which is what I want to find!!

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://techhelplist.com/index.php/tech-tutorials/40-python/59-get-variables-in-modpython). Btw, mod_python is appears to be very much deprecated and [mod_wsgi](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) is now recommended.

Comment: Many thanks, I will have a play over the next few days. Re Mod_python I saw a lot of comments about it being deprecated but if you look at the mod_python site (http://modpython.org) it seems after a couple of years of no development its now back and a new release 4.0 is imminent