# Get request on nginx; Call python script

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, nginx, python-requests

I searched through SO to find a solution to that problem (e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978152/how-to-post-form-data-via-ajax-to-a-python-script)), but I cannot get it to work. My aim was to call an index.html on my website, which calls a Python script with the GET parameters.

While searching on SO I found out that it's not possible with GET, I have to take POST. So now I want to call the index.html on my website, which calls a python script on the server with the POST parameters:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "foo.py",
            type: "POST",
            data: {foo: 'bar'}
       });
```

This is my Python script:

```
import cgi, cgitb 
cgitb.enable()

data = cgi.FieldStorage()

with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
  f.write(data["foo"].value)
```

When calling index.html with the post parameter `foo=foofoo` I first got a 403. But apparently that was related to NGINX, which I fixed with `error_page  405     =200 $uri;` (in case somebody has similar problems).

Now, that I am not getting a 403 anymore, I get a 404. I cannot understand why it would throw a 404. Both, the index.html and the script foo.py are present on the server.

I just want to call the Python script with the parameters from a GET/POST request...