# Saving Longitude and Latitude to a user profile in Django

Tags: python, html, django, location, geo

I was looking for a way to use HTML5 (and possibly JS) to save visitor/user Longitudnal & Latitudnal data to a database. I **do not wish to use  packages** out there as they seem a bit outdated and may break my code in future considerting their own reliance on other APIs.

I know there is a way around using AJAX, but I clearly dont know and understand it well enough to implement it.

My ask of the learned Lords is  - 1. Get Loc data 2. Send it to Python in dict or json or string format from where it can be further processed and saved.

Why you may ask - Good question. I would use it for displaying weather on the homepage and local twitter trends on a 'logged-in' page.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Cheers!

My JS code is below:

```
    // Set up global variable
var result;

function showPosition() {
    // Store the element where the page displays the result
    result = document.getElementById("result");

    // If geolocation is available, try to get the visitor's position
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback);
        result.innerHTML = "Getting the position information...";
    } else {
        alert("Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 geolocation.");
    }
};

// Define callback function for successful attempt
function successCallback(position) {
    result.innerHTML = [position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude];
}

// Define callback function for failed attempt
function errorCallback(error) {
    if (error.code == 1) {
        result.innerHTML = "You've decided not to share your position, but it's OK. We won't ask you again.";
    } else if (error.code == 2) {
        result.innerHTML = "The network is down or the positioning service can't be reached.";
    } else if (error.code == 3) {
        result.innerHTML = "The attempt timed out before it could get the location data.";
    } else {
        result.innerHTML = "Geolocation failed due to unknown error.";
    }
}

window.onload = showPosition;
```

Comment: Does this satisfy your needs? [MDN | Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API)

Comment: on your frontend you can use JS to call an api and update user profile with location. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: @shadow-lad: Appreciate your link, but I already have the Lat & Long... I'm new to this hence dont know how to attach screen shots. As mentioned. I am just looking at a solution to transfer the JS values to Python for analysis and Twitter trends.

Comment: @LinhNguyen on the front end everythng is working fine... I have whats needed there... i need to send it back to Django / Python to do the analysis. Much appreciated.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978152/how-to-post-form-data-via-ajax-to-a-python-script

Comment: @shaedrich How exactly? Which part of the code is interacting b/w JS and Python? and handing over data?

Comment: Just post data normally via [`$.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/Jquery.ajax/) and use `cgi.FieldStorage()` in python to retrieve the data.

Comment: :) I'm a novice... and haven't dealt with any... so not sure how to manage it.

Comment: I posted an answer that might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JS code:

```js
function successCallback(position) {
    result.innerHTML = [position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude];
    $.post('your-python-endpoint-url', {
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude
    });
}
```

In your python:

```py
def index(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print 'Raw Data: "%s"' % request.body   
    return HttpResponse("OK")
```

Change the method name and body according to your needs and don't forget to define a route in django.

Answer (score 1):

what works for me:

First I recommend you to use `models.PointField` on your model.

When I obtain the long/lat data on FE, I send it as form-data in the following format eg:

```
"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[14.215641,50.0100000001]}"
```

Then I map it to the model field and save it. It saves well and later I am able to query google geocoder or anything with it.

Comment: My fault, I forgot that Pointfield comes from GeoDjango and you do not wish to use packages. In that case, I recommend sending the data in the form described in @shaedrich's answer and then map save it to two `models.Floatfield`(s) on your model.